# Combining multiple PIG commands in single line

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, apache-pig

In a PIG script, is it possible to combine multiple commands in a single line, such that the output of one command line, instead of going into an output variable, can directly go as input to another command?

Answer (score 1):

It is allowed. 
But it doesn't optimize anything at runtime. 
It just confuses the syntax.

```
STORE(FORECH(LOAD '$file') GENERATE $0, $1) ) INTO 'output.txt';
```